# Docker expose not working

Tags: node.js, docker

### question:

I've created a simple site using Docker and Aurelia. The site runs in Docker, but is not accessible from my localhost. What I did:

---

**create container**

`docker build -t randy/node-web-app .`

`docker run -p 9000:9000 -d randy/node-web-app`

> 97f57c3d0da5d03f53b4ba893fdb866ca528e10e6c4a1b310726e514d8957650

**see if the scripts ran:**

`docker logs 97f57c3d0da5`

> Application Available At: http://localhost:9000

**Going into docker container terminal to see if the site is up:**

`docker exec -it 97f57c3d0da5 /bin/bash`

**See if it runs:**

`curl -i localhost:9000`

summary:

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>
> `<!DOCTYPE html>`

(I actually see the HTML that it should return, but that's too big to post here.)

**return to host terminal:**

`exit`

`curl -i localhost:9000`

> curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9000: Connection refused

How can I make sure I can access that site from my pc? In the first command, I've set expose on `9000:9000` so that shouldn't be a problem.

---

### Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:latest

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY . /usr/src/app

RUN npm install -g aurelia-cli
RUN npm install

EXPOSE 9000
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Comment: Are you listening on 127.0.0.1 only? `docker exec -it <container> netstat -an` should output 0.0.0.0:9000 not 127.0.0.1:9000

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used *Kitematic* instead of the normal version of Docker on the machine where I deployed this image. *Kitematic* maps the docker image to an (internal) IP address instead of the localhost of the host machine.

My answer was to use `192.168.1.67` as IP instead of `127.0.0.1`.

If you install Docker without *Kitematic*, this should not be an issue.